# Fail to build create_gazebo_plugins package on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, ros-hydro, macosx, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

upon

```
rosinstall_generator turtlebot_gazebo --rosdistro hydro --deps --wet-only --tar > turtlebot.list
wstool merge -t src turtlebot.list
wstool update -t src
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install
```

I end up with multiple "undefined symbol" errors. https://gist.github.com/anaderi/a321476446aa7f828635

These message are result of the following command: https://gist.github.com/anaderi/a321476446aa7f828635#file-link-cmd

Has anyone managed to build this package? (it is one of dependencies for turtlebot simulator (http://answers.ros.org/question/158641/turtlebot-navigation-on-hydro-osx/), which I'm actually interested in most of all)
(Sorry for not workable links, but is seems like a workaround for my lack of karma)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/169971/fail-to-build-create_gazebo_plugins-package-on-mac-os-x-10.9/) by [anaderi](https://answers.ros.org/users/18496/anaderi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following instructions work for me on OS X 10.9 after patching a few packages. This builds, but I haven't tested running it. `avahi` seems to be a Linux-only thing, so we won't install related packages. I guess you don't need them for you purpose.

**Edit:** forgot one patch.

```
mkdir turtlebot_ws
cd turlebot_ws
. /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash

# download source, but exclude zeroconf_avahi since this seems to be linux only thing
rosinstall_generator turtlebot_gazebo --rosdistro hydro --deps --wet-only --tar --exclude RPP zeroconf_avahi > turtlebot.list
wstool init -j8 src turtlebot.list

# manually install dependencies (rosdep rules are not complete on osx)
brew install libftdi0 libusb-compat

# the following is a dependency, but not needed for compiling. So you might need them to execute, or you might not.
brew install redis

# check what rosdep has to say
rosdep check --from-path src -i --skip-keys "avahi-utils ftdi-eeprom libftdi-dev avahi-daemon libusb-dev redis-server"
# this should only tell you to install "gcc" and "ros/hydro/zeroconf_avahi_suite", ignore those. 
# Install any additional packages coming up here by hand.

# apply patches
pushd src/openni_camera
curl https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera/pull/22.patch | patch -p1
popd

pushd src/ecl_core
curl https://github.com/stonier/ecl_core/pull/36.patch | patch -p1
popd

pushd src/ecl_lite
curl https://github.com/stonier/ecl_lite/pull/5.patch | patch -p1
popd

pushd src/kobuki_desktop
curl https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki_desktop/pull/30.patch | patch -p1
popd

pushd src/turtlebot_create_desktop
curl https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_create_desktop/pull/14.patch | patch -p1
popd

pushd src/kobuki_core
curl https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki_core/pull/14.patch  | patch -p1
popd

# build
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [meneguzzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/20501/meneguzzi/) on 2014-10-17**:
I just tried following your instructions to compile the turtlebot simulator in my Mac, it builds almost until the end, but it seems to fail to link libgazebo_ros_kobuki.dylib with exactly the same message as the OP. What can I be doing wrong?